# Commutative matrices

Tags: matrices

Knowing that $AB=BA$, find the matrices that commute with the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  3 & 4  \\
 \end{pmatrix}
I have assumed that multiplying matrix 
$\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d \end{pmatrix}
$ by the first one should be equal to multiplying the first one by $\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d \end{pmatrix}
$

Alright: 
$\begin{pmatrix}
a+2c & b+2d\\
3a+4c & 3b+4d\end{pmatrix}
$
 equals
$\begin{pmatrix}
a+3b & 2a+4b\\
c+3d & 2c+4d\end{pmatrix}
$

so:
$\begin{pmatrix}
a+2c = a+3b => 2c = 3b = 0\\
3a+4c = c +3d => a+c - d=0\\
b+2d = 2a+ 4b => -2a - 3b + 2d = 0\\
3b + 4d = 2c + 4d => 3b - 2c =0\end{pmatrix}
$
I was left with equations from which I have formed another matrix and used Gauss algorithm to evaluate it: 
$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
-2& -3 &0 &2& 0\\
0 &3 &-2& 0 &0\\
0 &-3& 2& 0 &0\end{pmatrix}
$
I made some changes (r3:=r3+r4; r4:=r4+r3; r2:=r2+2r1) and the upper diagonal matrix is:
$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0& -3 &2 &0& 0\\
0 &0 &0& 0 &0\\
0 &0& 0& 0 &0\end{pmatrix}
$

I was left with a set of equations
\begin{eqnarray}
a+ c + d      &=& 0 \\
-3b + 2c &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}
and now I'm stuck. Any help would be highly appreciated!

EDIT: A is the given matrix.

Comment: How do $A$ and $B$ relate to the given matrix?

Comment: @GitGud A is one matrix, B is another, so you could say that we search for B while A is already given (the ( 1 2 3 4) one)

Comment: @Pau: You need to clarify (in the question) that $A$ is the given matrix.

Comment: Your FIRST matrix seems wrong. Can you show the equations that led to it? Write the steps that changed the original $4$ equations into this matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have figured it out. The equations you end up with:

```
2c=3b
```

and

```
a+c=d
```

are correct. Basically this means that you can specify any TWO values of the matrix arbitrarily and then the remaining two are fixed by the above equations. For example, suppose you want to specify a and b. The, rewrite the equations like this:

```
c=3b/2
```

and

```
d=a+3b/2
```

Given, for example, a=2.345 and b=3.14 then

```
c=1.5*3.14
```

and

```
d=2.345+1.5*3.14
```

Get it?

Comment: thanks, i mean i do understand that you're putting in some random values as a and b and then rewrite c and d using those, but how can i write all matrices that fit the task if i could choose any values for it to fit?

Comment: Any matrix of the form [[a, b];[3b/2, a+3b/2]]. For any a and b.

Comment: ah i see, thanks! :D seems to be working for me. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Mark this answer as the solution if it solves your problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You should be left with a little more than two equations. If $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{bmatrix}$$

and $$B=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix},$$

then $$AB=\begin{bmatrix}a+2c & b+2d\\ 3a+4c & 3b+4d\end{bmatrix}$$

and $$BA=\begin{bmatrix}a+3b & 2a+4b\\ c+3d & 2c+4d\end{bmatrix}$$

which gives you $4$ equations.

Comment: thank you, I have done this and I also resolved BA by using Gauss algorithm, and I was left with the two last equations I wrote down in my question. I don't know what to do later with them...

Comment: @pau Then please edit your question how you got from the equations you get from $AB=BA$ to the equations you wrote.

Comment: sure, one moment!

Comment: already done, hope you'll know what to do next, im stuck!

Comment: i did it, check it out now please!

Comment: @Pau, your equations you wrote appear to be wrong. So check them again. For example, you write 2c=3b=0. This is wrong. Why did you put the final "=0" on the far right hand side?

Comment: The final equations you end up with are fine. 2c=3b and a+c=d. Any matrices [[a b];[c d]] satisfying these equations will commute with [[1 2];[3 4]].

Comment: See my answer for further explanation.

Comment: @pau $2c=3b=0$ is wrong, you only have $2c=3b$, or, equivalently, $2c-3b=0$.